# How to manually add nodes to Link List C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've made a Link List program in C# which creates a link list of 10 random nodes. But instead I want to manually enter the numbers myself. I'm not sure how to add a function so that I can manually add the numbers myself when the program runs rather than having them random generated? I've tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

```
namespace Linked_List
{
class Program
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Linked List: ");
        int size = 10;
        int[] a;

        a = new int[size + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("What value do you want to add?");
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Node n = new Node(a[i]);


            Node head = List(a, n);
            print_nodes(head); //used to print the values
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
    };

    static Node add(Node head, int data) //Add nodes
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        Node current;
        temp.data = data;
        temp.next = null; //next point will be null

        if (head == null) // if head is null
            head = temp;
        else
        {
            current = head;
            while (current.next != null)
                current = current.next;
            current.next = temp; //links to new node
        }
        return head;
    }

    static void print_nodes(Node head) //print the values in list
    {
        while (head != null) //while head is not null
        {
            Console.Write(head.data + " "); //outputs the numbers
            head = head.next;
        }
    }

    static Node List(int[] a, int n)
    {
        Node head = null; //head is originally null
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            head = add(head, a[i]);
        return head;
    }

   
}
}
```

Comment: If you made this code, you should know what is generating the random numbers. Knowing that, what have you tried to do so far? What is the task?

Comment: Yes I know what's making the random numbers, but I can't work out how to add the numbers manually if I get rid of the Random function

Comment: Where should the numbers come from?

Comment: I want to manually enter them. What I'm saying is, instead of using the random generator, I want to actually input them myself but not sure how to go about it

Comment: When the program runs or just hardcoded?

Comment: Have you looked into using Console.ReadLine() to take input from user manually

Comment: @Michael when the program runs

Comment: @Jawad Yes I know about that, but I will need to add another class somewhere won't I? That's where I'm confused

Comment: I've updated the code to show what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ask you to out in the values manually

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Linked List: ");
    int n = 10;
    Random r = new Random(); 
    int[] a;
    a = new int[n + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // here, no extra class needed

    Node head = List(a, n);
    print_nodes(head); 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```